# i get a not aNaNunction error and can't find out why

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs and have searched stackoverflow and tried many of the fixes. i have included the controller in my index.html. here's the html code:

```
    <div data-ng-app="expertise-choice" data-ng-controller="expertiseController">
    <label>
      Select your area of expertise or interest
      <select ng-model="expertise" ng-options="x for x in expertise"></select>
    </label>
  </div>
```

and my controller code is:

```
    var app = angular.module('expertise-choice' []);
    app.controller('expertiseController', function($scope) {
      $scope.expertise = ["African-American Studies", "Gender Studies", "Hispanic Studies", "More to come"];
    });
```

i have removed the [] in angular.module. i have tried putting () at the end of the code like })(); i cannot see any errors/typos. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same object in your `ng-model` and `ng-options`. When Angular attempts to bind the model, it will overwrite your options.

Solution: Use a different model

```
<select ng-model="selectedExpertise"
        ng-options="x for x in expertise">
</select>
```

Demo...

```js
angular.module('expertise-choice', [])
  .controller('expertiseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.expertise = ["African-American Studies", "Gender Studies", "Hispanic Studies", "More to come"];
  });
```

```html
<div data-ng-app="expertise-choice" data-ng-controller="expertiseController">
  <label>
    Select your area of expertise or interest
    <select ng-model="selectedExpertise"
            ng-options="x for x in expertise"></select>
  </label>
  <pre>selectedExpertise = {{selectedExpertise | json}}</pre>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your controller code where you declare your module:

```
var app = angular.module('expertise-choice', []);
app.controller('expertiseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.expertise = ["African-American Studies", "Gender Studies", "Hispanic Studies", "More to come"];
});
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed that one

Comment: Same with yours